# Any word contains only contains letters, numbers, underscores, and periods

Tags: regex, vba

I would like to write a pattern for `Like` function in VBA to validate **Any word with only letters, numbers, underscores, and periods**.

I could write like `[A-Za-z0-9_,]` which valides a character. But `[A-Za-z0-9_,]+` does not seem to check a word. Could anyone help?

Comment: What do you mean by `But [A-Za-z0-9_,]+ does not seem to check a word.` Which words are you referring to? The pattern matches 1 or more occurrences of what is listed in the character class.

Comment: on a side, `[A-Za-z0-9,]` validates commas not periods.

Comment: I mean `[a-zA-Z0-9._]+` does not validate `abc`.

Comment: Do you mean you need to find chunks of text that consist of ASCII letters, digits, `_` (word chars) and `.` between chars other than those listed before or start/end of string? Use custom boundaries to match whole "words", `(?:^|[^\w.])[\w.]+(?![\w.])`, or anchors to match whole strings, `^[\w.]+$`

Comment: No, I mean `[A-Za-z0-9_.]` seems to check only one character, but I need to check all the characters of a string.

Comment: No, I want to use `Like`.

Comment: Then you are not using regexps. In order to check a match context, you HAVE TO use a regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made it clear you only want to use `Like` which IMHO isn't your best option here. Best is to use `Regex` (as you have tagged yourself). But don't confuse the two, as with [`Like`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/like-operator) there are no modifiers like `+`. You'll have to concat the pattern **per** character. So instead of the very convenient `[A-Za-z0-9_,]+` you'll need something like: `[A-Za-z0-9_,][A-Za-z0-9_,][A-Za-z0-9_,]..etc..` which equals the length of your string value.

So one option would be:

```
Dim str As String: str = "Test_1,."
Dim pattern As String

pattern = Replace(Space(Len(str)), " ", "[A-Za-z0-9_,]")
If str Like pattern Then
    Debug.Print "Check"
Else
    Debug.Print "Nope"
End If
```

Another way would be to iterate over your string, per character:

```
Dim str As String: str = "Test_1,3"
Dim pattern As String: pattern = "[A-Za-z0-9_,]"

For x = 1 To Len(str)
    If Not Mid(str, x, 1) Like pattern Then
        Debug.Print "Nope"
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next x
Debug.Print "Check"
```

Comment: The Pattern should be [.0-9A-Z_a-z] because the Like operator requires the characters to be in ascending Ascii order.   "When you specify a range of characters, they must appear in ascending sort order, that is, from lowest to highest. Thus, [A–Z] is a valid pattern, but [Z–A] is not."

Comment: @freeflow, it made no difference to me. Can you apply your statement to an example where this becomes clear? AFAIK what you meant applies to ranges within the class, not placement of these ranges. Thus, the pattern is fine as is.

Comment: I just quoted the MS help page.  As we all know MS help is sometimes less than helpful but the point is important to know in case there are any strange effects or bugs.

Answer (score 1):

The usual convention in regex is that **word char** is either a *letter*
(upper or lower case), a *digit* or an "_" (underscore).

But you write that in your sense a word can contain also a *dot* (and as
I assume, also other "non-white" chars).

From this set of words you define **allowed words** actually as *[\w.]+*,
where:

- `\w` matches letters, digits and "_",
- `.` matches itself.

The only thing to add are border conditions, to guarantee that the pattern
does not match a **part** of a word, i.e.:

- before there should be either the start of text or any white char
  (positive lookbehind),
- after there should be either the end of text or any white char
  (positive lookahead).

So my proposition is:

```
(?<=^|\s)[\w.]+(?=\s|$)
```

Note that `\b` anchors can not be put instead of both my lookarounds, as they
will not work if a dot is either the first or the last char in your word.

Pattern like `[A-Za-z0-9_,]` as proposed in the other answer is also wrong,
for the same reason.

In my opinion the concept to use *Like* is also wrong, as it does not
take into account both "border conditions" (lookarounds) and you should
use just regex anyway.

Comment: There is no such thing as `\w` in `Like`. Unfortunatley, OP tagged `regex` but does not want to use it. Also, your statement about my answer is false. `Like` requires you to build a character class per character in string.